# ASP.NET Response - UTF-16 encoded file but nothing shown in the browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding, utf-8, utf-16

I am trying to send UTF-16BE text file as a HTTP Response from ASP.NET app.

```
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.BigEndianUnicode;
Response.WriteFile(filename);
```

but nothing shown as the result and Fiddler doesn't show any encoding

[image]

is it me or web browsers don't like utf-16 text ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your web browser is not the problem.

This code:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
context.Response.ContentEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.BigEndianUnicode;
context.Response.Write("Hello World");
```

Yields the expected content encoding:

> [image: encoding]

But as soon as you use `context.Response.WriteFile`, the content encoding gets removed. Not sure if this is a feature or not. I assume the software on the other end has to determine the content encoding based on the output returned.